# awk/bash append headers in many csv files

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I would like to transform the header of many csv files automatically using awk and bash scripts.

Currently, I am using the following code-block, which is working fine:

```
for FILE in *.csv;

do

awk 'FNR>1{print $0}' $FILE | awk 'NR == 1{print "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii,jjj,kkk,lll,mmm,nnn,...,zzz"}1' > OUT_$FILE

done
```

What these commands are doing is that it first removes the old header from `$FILE` and then <strike>append</strike> prepend a new comma-separated (very long) header `aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii,jjj,kkk,lll,mmm,nnn,...,zzz` to `$FILE` and then save the output to `OUT_$FILE`.

Currently, I am copying the part `aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii,jjj,kkk,lll,mmm,nnn,...,zzz` manually from another csv file and pasting into this field to replace the header from `$FILE`. While it is working, it is getting tedious, repetitive and time-consuming for many csv files.

Instead of copying the header manually, I am trying to extract the header from another csv file `new_headers.csv` and save to a new variable `$NEWHEAD`.

```
NEWHEAD=$(awk 'NR==1{print $0}' new_headers.csv)
```

While I can view the extracted header `$NEWHEAD`, I am not sure how to merge this command into previous workflow to <strike>append</strike> prepend the headers from `$FILE`.

I will certainly appreciate any suggestions to resolve this problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Aside: To "append" something is to add it _to the end_; if you're putting a header at the beginning, you're prepending rather than appending.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you for this suggestion, I have changed the word from 'append' to 'prepend'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
newheader=$(head -n 1 new_headers.csv)

for file in *.csv
do
    {
        printf '%s\n' "$newheader"
        tail -n +2 "$file" 
    } > OUT_"$file"
done
```

**notes:**

- `head -n 1` outputs the first line of a file
- `tail -n +2` outputs all the lines but the first
- `{ }` is to group commands, so that you redirect their output as a whole

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I tested the solution just now. It was easy to follow and worked!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for "inplace" editing:

```
awk -i inplace 'NR==1{hdr=$0} {print (FNR>1 ? $0 : hdr)}' new_headers.csv *.csv
```

Comment: This is a neat solution! It reduces many lines into a single line to replace the header from `*.csv` using the input from `new_headers.csv`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the header inside `awk` script, like this

```
awk '
  BEGIN{
    do {
      h = (h) ? (h "\n" line) : line
    } while ((getline line <"new_header.csv") > 0)
}

...
'
```

and `h` contains the new header.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work, it doesn't produces the output as expected...

Comment: This does not produce any output, it's showing how to read a file in `awk`, then you need to replace the `...` by whatever you want to do with the header `h`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {header=$0; next} 
               {print (FNR==1?header:$0) > (FILENAME".updated")}' new_header.csv other files...
```

capture the first record from the header file and replace the first lines from the rest of the files, updated files will have suffix ".updated".

**caveat emptor** not tested.

Comment: yes, right. I assumed the header file has just the header but might be better to make it extract the first line.

Comment: This solution is also working, I have made minimal changes to your suggestion, by changing 'updated' from suffix to be prefix because the suffix will modify the csv filetype from `.csv` to be `.csv.updated`.

`awk 'NR==FNR {header=$0; next}{print (FNR==1?header:$0) > ("updated_"FILENAME)}' new_header.csv *.csv`

Thank you for your suggestion!